# What does `precision mediump float` mean?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, terminology, fragment-shader

In the [learningwebgl tutorial1](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28) I've found an interesting line in the fragment shader.

```
precision mediump float;
```

I've found an article about it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/Use-mediump-precision-in-WebGL-when-possible), but I still can't understand what does it mean?

And if I remove this line, nothing changes. Everything is the same.
So what does `precision mediump float` mean?

Comment: Have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6336285/344480), especially the GLSL specification. Does it answer your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In OpenGL ES 2.0 / GLSL, where do you need precision specifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366416/in-opengl-es-2-0-glsl-where-do-you-need-precision-specifiers)

Comment: You did not understand what mediump means from your article, because it does not explain it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This determines how much precision the GPU uses when calculating floats. `highp` is high precision, and of course more intensive than `mediump` (medium precision) and `lowp` (low precision).

Some systems do not support `highp` at all, which will cause code not to work at all on those systems.

On systems that DO support `highp`, you will see a performance hit, and should use `mediump` and `lowp` wherever possible. A good rule of thumb that I saw was:

- `highp` for vertex positions,
- `mediump` for texture coordinates,
- `lowp` for colors.

Comment: Thanks you. And is it possible somehow, if high/medium/low p is supported or not?

Comment: Different systems will support different settings. The only thing I've ever read about NOT being supported is high. I think medium and low should be safe, but it's something to keep in mind some day if some code isn't running on a device and you can't find a reason :)

Comment: Thanks for that rule of thumb, really helpful, do you know where I can find the actual precision of each in terms of the mantissa of each type? I know it doesn't really matter I'm just curious about it.

Comment: @TrevorHart - try this: http://litherum.blogspot.com/2013/04/precision-qualifiers-in-opengl-es.html

Comment: Is this GLSL or GLSL ES feature? Is it deprecated?

Comment: It's GLSL ES. In practice, it is *mediump/lowp* that may not be supported, specifically on desktop GPUs. On mobile, there is usually reduced precision support.

Comment: What is the trade-off that's being made here? Does highp make the shader run slower?