# Error while running OpenGL code on Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyqt5, pyopengl

I've just installed OpenGL to use with Python 3.7 and PyQt5, installation was without any errors. When I try to run the example codes given with PyQt5 for OpenGL, only 1 example code runs, all other gave error. Following are the error associated with each file:

openglwindow.py

> self.m_gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initializeOpenGLFunctions'

grabber.py

> File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
>
> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
>
> err = 1282,
>
> description = b'invalid operation',
>
> baseOperation = glLightfv,
>
> ...

hellogl.py

> File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
>
> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
>
> err = 1282,
>
> description = b'invalid operation',
>
> baseOperation = glGetString,
>
> cArguments = (GL_VENDOR,)
>
> )

overpainting.py

> File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
>
> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
>
> err = 1282,
>
> description = b'invalid operation',
>
> baseOperation = glGenLists,
>
> cArguments = (1,),
>
> result = 0
>
> )

samplebuffers.py

> File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
>
> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
>
> err = 1282,
>
> description = b'invalid operation',
>
> baseOperation = glMatrixMode,
>
> cArguments = (GL_PROJECTION,)
>
> )

I am using windows 10 and OpenGL version is 3.1. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching I found that by default Windows uses ANGLE, a library that implements OpenGL ES on top of Direct 3D.

So to force application to use OpenGL instead of ANGLE, I added

```
QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)
```

Also, I used [Unofficial Windows PyOpenGL Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl).

I got the solution from following 2 sources:

[Source 1 - RiverBank Computing](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2014-December/035217.html)

[Source 2 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399801/specifying-opengl-desktop-instead-of-es-for-qt5)