# Threejs normal values in shader are set to 0

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to get this [tutorial](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-2/) to work but I ran into two issues, one of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058064/why-do-i-need-to-define-a-precision-value-in-webgl-shaders). The other one is the following.

For convenience this is the code that is supposed to work and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksx2vz9j/).

Vertex-shader:

```
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
attribute vec3 position;
uniform vec3 normal;
varying vec3 vNormal;

void main() {
    test = 0.5;
    vNormal = normal;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Fragment-shader:
    varying mediump vec3 vNormal;

```
void main() {
    mediump vec3 light = vec3(0.5, 0.2, 1.0);

    // ensure it's normalized
    light = normalize(light);

    // calculate the dot product of
    // the light to the vertex normal
    mediump float dProd = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, light));

    // feed into our frag colour
    gl_FragColor = vec4(dProd, // R
                        dProd, // G
                        dProd, // B
                        1.0);  // A
}
```

The values for `normal` in the vertex shader or at least the values for `vNormal` in the fragment shader seem to be 0. The sphere that is supposed to show up stays black. As soon as I change the values for `gl_FragColor` manually the sphere changes colors. Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your vertex shader the `vec3 normal` should be an attribute (since each vertex has a normal) not a uniform:

```
attribute vec3 normal;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vdfn1pcn/) is the working version of your code.

Comment: you're my hero! Thanks a lot!