# GLSL Error: "Type should be float or int"

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to compile a shader, and it is compiling on Intel HD on one PC, but not on AMD drivers on another PC.

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 330
precision mediump float;
precision lowp sampler2D;

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 WorldViewMatrix;
in vec3 position;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    texCoord = TexCoord;
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * WorldViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 330
precision mediump float;
precision lowp sampler2D;

uniform vec4 TextureHueColor;
uniform sampler2D TextureUnit;
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture(TextureUnit, texCoord) * TextureHueColor;
}
```

On AMD drivers, I am getting:

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:3: error(#228) Type should be float or int
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I am a beginner, and have no idea what is wrong with this shader, to me it looks fine. Anyone spot what's wrong?

Comment: Try to remove `precision lowp sampler2D;`.

Comment: @MathuSumMut: Then you probably didn't remove it correctly. If you did, then line 3 would either be an empty space or a comment, neither of which could possibly result in getting the same error. So either you got a *different* error or you only think you removed the statement.

Comment: @MathuSumMut: Use your debugging skills. Create errors in the file before that line number and see what happens. Or debug into your code and read the string right before you pass it to `glShaderSource`. *Prove* that you have really changed the string. Because right now, all evidence points to you not having done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default `precision` qualifiers in GLSL 3.30 cannot be applied to sampler types. Or any type other than `int` or `float`.

Also, FYI: when using desktop GLSL (as opposed to GLSL ES), the `precision` qualifiers accomplish nothing. They're ignored; they exist solely for compatibility with GLSL ES shaders.

Comment: Apparently, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6336285/5007383, `precision lowp sampler2D;` is a valid statement, but only in OpenGL ES, not regular OpenGL. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @MathuSumMut: I did some more digging and found that my statement was true in GLSL 3.30, but was eventually changed in 4.40 to allow sampler types (and later any opaque type). So AMD's driver is correct.