# Differing floating point behaviour between uniform and constants in GLSL

Tags: opengl, floating-point, glsl, shader, precision

I am trying to implement emulated double-precision in GLSL, and I observe a strange behaviour difference leading to subtle floating point errors in GLSL.

Consider the following fragment shader, writing to a 4-float texture to print the output.

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 Output
uniform float s;
void main()
{
  float a = 0.1f;
  float b = s;

  const float split = 8193.0; // = 2^13 + 1

  float ca = split * a;
  float cb = split * b;

  float v1a = ca - (ca - a);
  float v1b = cb - (cb - b);

  Output = vec4(a,b,v1a,v1b);
}
```

This is the output I observe

**GLSL output with uniform :**

```
a = 0.1            0x3dcccccd
b = 2.86129e-06    0x36400497
v1a = 0.0999756    0x3dccc000
v1b = 2.86129e-06  0x36400497
```

Now, with the given values of `b1` and  `b2` as inputs, the value of `v2b` does not have the expected result. Or at least it does not have the same result as on CPU (as seen [here](https://ideone.com/y4OTKR)):

**C++ output :**

```
a = 0.100000     0x3dcccccd
b = 0.000003     0x36400497
v1a = 0.099976   0x3dccc000
v1b = 0.000003   0x36400000
```

Note the discrepancy for the value of `v1b` (`0x36400497` vs `0x36400000`).

So in an effort to figure out what was happening (and who was right) I attempted to redo the computation in GLSL, replacing the uniform value by a constant, using a slightly modified shader, where I replaced the uniform by it value.

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 Output
void main()
{
  float a = 0.1f;
  float b = uintBitsToFloat(0x36400497u);

  const float split = 8193.0; // = 2^13 + 1

  float ca = split * a;
  float cb = split * b;

  float v1a = ca - (ca - a);
  float v1b = cb - (cb - b);

  Output = vec4(a,b,v1a,v1b);
}
```

This time, I get the same output as the C++ version of the same computation.

**GLSL output with constants :**

```
a = 0.1            0x3dcccccd
b = 2.86129e-06    0x36400497
v1a = 0.0999756    0x3dccc000
v1b = 2.86102e-06  0x36400000
```

My question is, what makes the floating point computation behave differently between a uniform variable and a constant ? Is this some kind of behind-the-scenes compiler optimization ?

Here are my OpenGL vendor strings from my laptop's intel GPU, but I also observed the same behaviour on a nVidia card as well.

```
Renderer : Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
Vendor   : Intel
OpenGL   : 4.5.0 - Build 23.20.16.4973
GLSL     : 4.50 - Build 23.20.16.4973
```

Comment: you are comparing different things. If I get it right the discrepancy is on CPU not on GLSL ...  `const float` might get optimized by compiler and compute at compile time  as `double` hence the difference between variable and constant. There is usually also  difference between CPU and GPU results (not your case however) because GPU floats are not always standard floats they have sometimes different number of bits ...

Comment: If you change `float v1b = cb - (cb - b);` to `float tempb = cb - b; float v1b = cb - tempb;` (and similarly for `v1a`), does the behavior change?

Comment: Try adding the `precise` modifier to `v1a` and `v1b` as this looks like a case where floating-point re-association or FMA contraction are being applied as a performance optimization (allowed by default, I think), changing the result.

Comment: re: @Spektre : the problem is that the first version has the wrong result (as it does not conform to IEEE 754 standard the other two follow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as mentioned by [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/780717/njuffa), in the comments, the problem was solved by using the **`precise` modifier** on the values which depended on rigorous IEEE754 operations:

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 Output
uniform float s;
void main()
{
  float a = 0.1f;
  float b = s;

  const float split = 8193.0; // = 2^13 + 1

  precise float ca = split * a;
  precise float cb = split * b;

  precise float v1a = ca - (ca - a);
  precise float v1b = cb - (cb - b);

  Output = vec4(a,b,v1a,v1b);
}
```

**Output :**

```
a = 0.1            0x3dcccccd
b = 2.86129e-06    0x36400497
v1a = 0.0999756    0x3dccc000
v1b = 2.86102e-06  0x36400000
```

Edit: it is higly probable that only the last `precise` are needed to constrain the operations leading to its computation to avoid unwanted optimizations.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I am working on WebGL 1.0, not 2.0, which does not support the "precise" qualifier. Do you know what can be done there?

Comment: How about `precision highp` ?

Comment: The reason that I don't want to migrate to WebGL 2.0 is that it is not supported on some mobile devices: e.g. on iphones

Comment: Here's what I would try (referring to some of the comments answers to my original question) :
- Try to add intermediary variables to store the result of `ca-a`et al.
- Try to make these intermediary variables `volatile` (if this keyword works with OpenGL ES...)

Comment: unfortunately "volatile" is just a reserved word there. There is no any support for them in the WebGL2. Intermediate variables are not helping as well

Answer (score 3):

**GPU** do not necessarily have/use **IEEE 754** some implementations have smaller number of bits so there is no brainer the result will be different. Its the same as you would compare `float` vs. `double` results on **FPU**. However you can try to enforce precision if your **GLSL** implementation allows it see:

- [In OpenGL ES 2.0 / GLSL, where do you need precision specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6336285/2521214)

  not sure if it is also for standard **GL/GLSL** as I never used it.

In worse case use `double` and `dvec` if your **GPU** allows it but beware there are no 64bit interpolators yet (at least to my knowledge).

To rule out rounding due to passing results by texture see:

- [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214)

You can also check the number of mantissa bits on your **GPU** simply by printing

```
1.0+1.0/2.0
1.0+1.0/4.0
1.0+1.0/8.0
1.0+1.0/16.0
...
1.0+1.0/2.0^i
```

The `i` of last number not printed as `1.0` is the number of the mantissa bits. So you can check if it is 23 or not ...